# Select items that has no specifc value

Tags: mysql

I have product table - each one of them has several categories; each category has a main column.  (I also have a categories table and a product_categories table.)

If `main = 1` -> it's the main category

I want to select all products that don't have at all a main category (all categories related to this product don't have a `main = 1` column).

This is the way to select all main categories:

```
SELECT *
  FROM categories
 WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT category_id
                FROM `product_categories`
               WHERE main = 1);
```

How do I find the products without a main category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned *I want to **select all products that doesn't have at all a main category** (all categories related to this product doesnt have a main = 1 column).*

This is what you're after

```
select * from products where prod_id not in (select distinct prod_id from categories where main =1);
```

I kind of tried it.

```
mysql> desc products;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| prod_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc categories;
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| prod_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cat_id  | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| main    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from products;
+---------+-------+
| prod_id | name  |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | prod1 |
|       2 | prod2 |
|       3 | prod3 |
|       4 | prod4 |
+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from categories;
+---------+--------+------+
| prod_id | cat_id | main |
+---------+--------+------+
|       1 |      1 |    1 |
|       1 |      2 |    2 |
|       2 |      1 |    2 |
|       2 |      1 |    3 |
|       3 |      2 |    1 |
|       3 |      4 |    2 |
+---------+--------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from products where prod_id not in (select distinct prod_id from categories where main =1);
+---------+-------+
| prod_id | name  |
+---------+-------+
|       2 | prod2 |
|       4 | prod4 |
+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM products WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM `product_categories` WHERE main =1)

Answer (score 1):

I have found NOT IN prove troublesome in the past from the point of view of performance. If the above suggestions are slow, you might care to try...

```
SELECT *
    FROM PRODUCTS
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                          FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORIES
                          WHERE MAIN = 1 AND
                                PRODUCT_CATEGORIES.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCTS.ID)
```

although as a fan of Knuth's dictum, I'd suggest you code it whichever way you find easiest first, and only worry about it if a problem does arise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the field "product_id" in "product_categories" and a table "products" with the field "id".

The query looks like ;

```
select p.*
from products p
left join product_categories pc on pc.product_id = p.id and pc.main = 1
where pc.category_id is null
group by p.id
```

Comment: I do not think that his will work the way it is supposed to be.